# Multiple instances of same jQuery plugin

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In an aspx page I am calling a jquery plugin for two listboxes as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $("select.select_AdditionalLanguages").custSelectBox();      
     $("select.select_Organisations").custSelectBox();
});
```

Problem is, in the plugin jQuery(this) holds the listbox which was loaded last. Please suggest how to solve this issue. I have also tried the below without any success.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        var languages = $('<%=AdditionalLanguages.ClientID%>');
        if (languages) {
            languages.custSelectBox();
        }
        alert(languages);
        var organizations = $('<%=Organisations.ClientID%>');
        if (organizations) {
            organizations.custSelectBox();
        }
    });
```

***EDIT:***

Managed to solved this issue by having same class name for both the listboxes and then passing both the list box objects to the plugin 
$('select.select_field').custSelectBox(null, $('#EditUsers_Organisations'), $('#EditUsers_AdditionalLanguages')); 
This might not be the best solution but nothing else worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solved this issue by having same class name for both the listboxes and then passing both the list box objects to the plugin $('select.select_field').custSelectBox(null, $('#EditUsers_Organisations'), $('#EditUsers_AdditionalLanguages')); This might not be the best solution but nothing else worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

two list box will have 2 different ids

$.('#listbox1').custSelectBox();

$.('#listbox2').custSelectBox();

Comment: I have tried with ID's and Class. Plug Is loading but I am getting only one instance.